# How to start L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim() with user's current location

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to develop a routing system and I want to know how can start with the user's current location from A point?

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
    //   waypoints: [null],
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng( user's current location),
        L.latLng(" string address")
    ],
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    show: true,
    language: 'it',
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    autoRoute: true
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the user coordinates to use them as input. In leaflet you can use e.latlng.lng and e.latlng.lat.
Using this, your example should look like this:

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
//   waypoints: [null],
waypoints: [
    L.latLng( e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng),
    L.latLng(" string address")
],
routeWhileDragging: true,
show: true,
language: 'it',
geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
autoRoute: true 
}).addTo(map)
```

Comment: Hi, I'll accept your answer but before that help with this, I have var latitude = position.coords.latitude; var longitude = position.coords.longitude; how can I assign these variables to e.latlng.lat and e.latlng.lng?

Comment: if you already have these variables just use those. e.latlng is leaflet's way of providing the coordinates.